# Should I change my HTML files to PHP

Tags: php, html

my question is if there is any reason at all not to just convert all of my HTML files into PHP files so that I can put PHP code into them. Are there some cases where naming a file *.php will make the HTML parse incorrectly?

So is there any point in keeping HTML documents at all, then?

Comment: How is [tag:imagemagick-convert] relevant?

Comment: Answer: No, but don't just rename plain `.html` files arbitrarily. `.php` simply tells the *server* to send it through the *server-side* PHP parser. This is a default setting. You can, of course, tell your server (Apache, nginx, etc.) to send `.html` through the parser as `.php`. But, technically, you do not need to do this with files that should just be served as-is (like plain, no PHP HTML files).

Comment: And on the second point, HTML is parsed by the *client*, e.g., the browser. Unless PHP code is not being parsed and being sent to the client *as HTML*, you will not be affecting the parsing of the intended HTML as a pure answer. (Notwithstanding broken or borked PHP in a file erroring out and the client seeing an error or something other than the intended output.)

Comment: @Nile, it happens that the tag `convert` is an alias of `imagemagick-convert` (as "convert" is the name of one of the primary binaries used by imagemagick).  Users with poor tagging skill fall into that trap frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to think it the other way round. There should be a reason to convert HTML to PHP. If it doesn't exist, then don't do it.

If you do, there would be more "latency" between the user request and the web page render, because of the interpretation of the PHP server of your page. Additionally, you add complexity to your system (server configuration, security fixes, etc).

Comment: Do you mean that naming all your pages .php will cause them all to be parsed, regardless of whether or not there actually is any php in the code?  I'm assuming it would be fine for all of your pages to be php (or set the server to parse html for php) if you have php in every single page, like a CMS?

Answer (score 3):

If your server is configured to parse *.php files for PHP, but to just serve up the HTML files, then renaming your HTML files to have .php extensions will slow things down.

Comment: The reasoning behind this answer is that a file system-only response will always outperform a procedural parsing response. I'd be interested in seeing how *much* of an impact parsing a file with no PHP content would be, and what level of load the differences would be measurable, although something tells me it's not that simple. On the other hand, lots of systems use Apache's `mod_rewrite` and MVC patterns (http://slimframework.com not withstanding) to run at least a little PHP for many, most, sometimes all requests.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Each PHP process requires a huge amount of RAM, because of PHP itself and because of the libraries loaded by the PHP module, such as PDO, gd, ...

Comment: @MathieuImbert - Oh, and that's not already in place in a server which *could* serve PHP but is instead serving plain HTML files?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Not necesseraly. If no PHP parsing is required, the webserver won't start a PHP exec.

Comment: @MathieuImbert - Like I said, I would *love* to see an academic demonstration. There's *lots* of techniques that improve performance, like nginx, slim, and oh removing PHP altogether. That's beside the point. This is guesswork and prone to "buts, ifs, and ontheotherhands".

Comment: @JaredFarrish I understand your point. I tried it in production and we used to have a lot of PHP/MySQL websites with no dynamic content. We switched to static files. But you don't need academic demonstration. Try it.

Comment: @MathieuImbert - And I do support the general premise (PHP parsing will add some level of overhead), my conjecture is *how much* and *when will it become noticeable*. If you serve 50 files to one customer an hour, chances are, there's little to be worried about. It is best, though, not to go about it this way, just like driving with your elbows is possible but kinda silly and not a good way to handle it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If you have enough traffic, you will notice the difference. I'm not talking about tweaking your site to make it static. I mean if you use PHP do render static HTML, you are not driving with your elbow, you are driving to visit your neighbour. But of course I'm not talking about 50 hits an hour, but millions a day.

Comment: @MathieuImbert - And this was the reason I said I'd like to see an academic, thought-driven approach to deconstructing the issue. I've run a site which, for seven+ years, has had on average 100 or so users, 15 or so concurrent on normal loads at peak, and occasionally had several thousand concurrent for short periods. This is meaningful. Not everyone, and I'd say most, don't encounter the kind of load you're describing, and are possibly more like my departmental site.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If you want to try, it then try it. Measure the memory used by one PHP process. Multiply but the number of required process. Let's say `total = n * proc`. If you don't use PHP, `n = 0`. It will always be less than using PHP. It doesn't make a difference with al little traffic. But when you come to a point where you need to buy a new server, it's a good time to start dropping what is not needed. My initial point was, why would you use PHP to server static pages?

Comment: @MathieuImbert - That's not what the OP asked. Maybe that's the misunderstanding. (And *yes*, I understand the point. The *effect* is determined by the use case. Building out for Facebook/Yahoo-level request levels should not *always* drive strategy, but the point is, *have a strategy*.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes you are right we are not talking about the initial question anymore ;)

Comment: @MathieuImbert - The take-home is *it's naive to think there's a one-size-fits-all* answer, because there are so many variations and variables. A scalable approach might be warranted, it might not be, and it may take a usual, unexpected or terse form. The point is, don't just *do*, *think*.

Answer (score 0):

A file named *.php that is entirely HTML will still parse correctly as HTML. As others have already noted, however, there is a performance difference between that and the .html extension.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that all .php files need to pass though the php parser.  Thus you'll be putting slightly more load on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Something else you could do is set in `httpd.conf` `application/x-httpd-php` to also recognise `.html` extensions as a PHP file. That way you won't have to change the extension.